# Access struct fields within a function by string argument

Tags: julia

Say I have a struct,

```
struct MyStruct

a
b

end
```

Is there some way to write a function like the following

```
function doSomething(x::MyStruct,fieldName::String)

y = x.fieldName

return f(y)

end
```

I could not find anything about this in the documentation / forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to get the value only few times redrikekre's solution is OK. However, using metaprogramming you can write code without efficiency penalty, see the `getDoSomething2()` function below.

Consider those three functions:

```
function doSomethingNative(x)
  return x.a
end

function doSomething(x, name::String)
    return getproperty(x, Symbol(name))
end

function getDoSomething2(name::String)
     field = Symbol(name)
     code = quote
         (obj) -> obj.$field
     end
     return eval(code)
end
```

Now the setup:

```
using BenchmarkTools
struct MyStruct
          a
          b
end
x = MyStruct(5,6)
```

Now the benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime doSomethingNative($x)
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5

julia> @btime doSomething($x,"a")
  36.266 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5

julia> const doSomething2 = getDoSomething2("a");

julia> @btime doSomething2($x)
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5
```

If you run `@code_native doSomethingNative(x)` and `@code_native doSomething2(x)` you will see that the assembly output is identical.

Answer (score 3):

You can access fields with `Symbol`s, so you can convert the string to a symbol and then use `getproperty`:

```
julia> struct MyStruct
           a
           b
       end

julia> function doSomething(x::MyStruct, name::String)
           s = Symbol(name)
           return getproperty(x, s)
       end
doSomething (generic function with 1 method)

julia> doSomething(MyStruct(1, 2), "a")
1
```

Note, however, that this will probably be very inefficient, since the compiler most likely can't see through this and thus your code might be type-unstable, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/.